# JSON Data retrieved, how do I display it in my label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, label

I've retrieved data to my iOS app from my Drupal database using the below code:

**.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *userData;
```

**.m**

```
self.userData = [NSMutableArray new];

            NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
            [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                self.userData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
               NSLog(@"%@",self.userData);


            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];

     self.userData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     self.userBio.text = self.userData[0][@"userbio"];
```

self.userData is populated, so I know my data has successfully been returned. Does anyone know how I would display the JSON returned field in a UIlabel? I'm just not sure how I would write this line of code (newb, sorry). My field name is **userbio**.

**Here's how the data structure is returned** (incase it's of any use): [image]

**UPDATE:** *`NSLog(@"userData = %@", self.userData);`* returns this in the console:

> 2015-10-25 11:22:06.601 [7605:2738034]

```
userData = (
>         {
>         userbio = "No user bio available at this time.";
>         "users_name" = "<a href=\"/user/20\" title=\"View user profile.\" class=\"username\" xml:lang=\"\" about=\"/user/20\"
> typeof=\"sioc:UserAccount\" property=\"foaf:name\"
> datatype=\"\">Brittany</a>";
>     },
```

Comment: What is the value of `[self.userData objectForKey:@"userbio"]`? Maybe the structure of the data isn't what you expect. Did you log `self.userData`? Does it contain what you expect and where you expect it? Update your question with the output of the log.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes! When I log self.userData, the console returns: userbio = "user's description/bio here."

Comment: Like I said, update your question with the output of `NSLog(@"userData = %@", self.userData);`.

Comment: @rmaddy See updated :)

Comment: The leading parentheses indicates that `self.userData` is actually an array of dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy Something to note: self.userData is an NSMutableDictionary - though should it be an NSMutableArray? If so, how would that line of code look for setting self.userBio.text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an NSDictionary the code would look like this:

```
self.myLabelName.text = self.userData[@"userbio"];
```

If it's an NSArray of NSDictionaries it would look like:

```
self.myLabelName.text = [self.userData firstObject][@"userbio"];
```

That's assuming that the array contains only one dictionary, otherwise you would have to access each element: self.userData[0], self.userData[1], etc.